# Image not load local file with require

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to load a local image but with the require() method it keeps giving me error , how I can pass in this case this.props.image in require.

my code:

Card.js

I tried this:

```
class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
           <Image source={require(this.props.image)} style={styles.imageBox}/>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and this:

```
class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
           <Image source={require({this.props.image})} style={styles.imageBox}/>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = { header: null }

  render() {
    return (
    <Card
      image='./img/demo.jpg'
    />  
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is this syntax? Why are you doing `require`?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: because on the page of react-native says that {uri:'http://www.exemple.it/image.jpg'} is for load online image and require('./image.jpg') is for load local image @Baruch

Comment: this is the error : Invalid call at line 41: require(this.props.imagine) @Nedko Dimitrov

Comment: why it is require(this.props.imagine) in your example you are using require({this.props.image})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in `ReactNative` documentation for Image says

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

So Try this 
first load image in App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = { header: null }

  render() {
    return (
    <Card
      image={require('./img/demo.jpg')}
    />  
   );
  }
}
```

And Card.js is the same like you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first import an image and use it.

```
App.js

import image from './img/demo.jpg';

class App extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = { header: null }

  render() {
    return (
    <Card
      image={image}
    />  
   );
  }
}

card.js

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
           <Image source={this.props.image} style={styles.imageBox}/>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

OR

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = { header: null }

  render() {
    return (
    <Card
      image={'logo.png'}
    />  
   );
  }
}

card.js

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
           <img src={require(`./img/${this.props.image}`)} alt='img' style={styles.imageBox}/>

       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have more or less the same problem with react navigation if I pass a value to another page I do not always see the image with require example: <Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', {image: '../image.jpg'})}> . the code for the source of the image is this.props.navigation.state.params.image